# How to handle order change in an ordered <select> element

Tags: c#, html, blazor

Suppose I have the following code to produce a drop down element and a text input to change the name of an item in a sorted list:

```
@page "/"

<input @bind="@SelectedFoo.Name"/>

<select @bind="SelectedFooId">
    @foreach (var foo in MyFoos.OrderBy(e => e.Name))
    {
        <option value="@foo.Id">@foo.Name</option>
    }
</select>

@code
{
    private Foo SelectedFoo { get; set; }
    private string _selectedFooId;

    private string SelectedFooId
    {
        get => _selectedFooId;
        set
        {
            _selectedFooId = value;
            SelectedFoo = MyFoos.Find(e => e.Id == _selectedFooId);
        }
    }

    private List<Foo> MyFoos { get; } = new()
    {
        new Foo { Name = "A Foo", Id = "0" },
        new Foo { Name = "B Foo", Id = "1" },
        new Foo { Name = "C Foo", Id = "2" }
    };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SelectedFooId = MyFoos.First().Id;
    }


    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

If I now select "C Foo" and change its name to "Ab Foo" it is now correctly ordered in the drop down above "B Foo", but the select element now displays "B Foo" instead of the "Ab Foo" as selected.

[image]

[image]

How do I update the select element's selected item to reflect the change in order?

- Framework: .NET 6.0
- Browser: Any

Comment: This is a good MRE but no repro. Please add the Blazor version and specify which Browser(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the @key directive like this:

```
<option @key="foo" value="@foo.Id">@foo.Name</option>
```